# Android studio Glide

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

Can someone help me with this Mediadata Retriever?

========================================================================================================

LogCat:

```
    Process: com.musicapp.android.musicapp, PID: 8376
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            at com.musicapp.android.musicapp.MusicCustomAdapter.getSongArt(MusicCustomAdapter.java:87)
com.musicapp.android.musicapp.MusicCustomAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MusicCustomAdapter.java:42)
```

code:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.artist_Name.setText(newSong_list.get(position).getArtist_Name());
        holder.songTitle.setText(newSong_list.get(position).getSongTitle());
        holder.songDuration.setText(newSong_list.get(position).getSongDuration());
 42       byte[] image = getSongArt(newSong_list.get(position).getPath());
        if (image != null){
            Glide.with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(image)
                    .into(holder.SongCover);
        }else{
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(R.drawable.allsongs)
                    .into(holder.SongCover);
        }


=============================================================================

        private byte[] getSongArt(String uri){
            MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    87        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(uri);
            byte[] art = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
            mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
            return art;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Other that show me you code.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.artist_Name.setText(newSong_list.get(position).getArtist_Name());
        holder.songTitle.setText(newSong_list.get(position).getSongTitle());
        holder.songDuration.setText(newSong_list.get(position).getSongDuration());

String image = newSong_list.get(position).getPath());
        if (image != null){
            Glide.with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(image)
                    .into(holder.SongCover);
        }else{
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(R.drawable.allsongs)
                    .into(holder.SongCover);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I tried that, but the images does not load....I did a Toast and I see that the image variable is not null